# Need to execute a cron job

Tags: login, cron, wp-cron, authentication

I need a cron job to execute the following url

> http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myvideoblog/mvb_main.php&action=processfeed&updatefeed=67

The problem is that it requires to be logged in as admin, what are my options? I've tried a few plugins but they use hooks instead of just executing a url and the cron jobs provided by the control panel does not log in to the website.

Comment: I don't think he is necessarily asking for a plugin, just a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your option using WP internals would be to use the HTTP API along with `wp schedule event`

Create a scheduled event, something like:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_schedule');
add_action('execute_my_url', 'do_this_daily');

function my_schedule() {
    $timestamp = //some time you want it to run
    wp_schedule_event($timestamp, 'daily', 'execute_my_url');
}

function do_this_daily() {
    wp_remote_get( '../ =myvideoblog/mvb_main.php&action=processfeed&updatefeed=67', $args);
}
```

This is a simple example please refer to the codex for additional techniques and/or arguments.

- [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)
- [wp schedule event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)

It's important to note WP cron only triggers when someone visits your WordPress site, fora true stateless cron you would need to use something at the server level or a better wrapper.